# How to translate this .htaccess to IIS web.config?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, backbone.js, history, web-config

What is the proper way to convert this lines to IIS web.config? I am trying to use Backbone Router with history support. It works perfect with .htaccess but i have no idea about how to do this on IIS.

.htaccess file

```
# html5 pushstate (history) support:
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

this is the script included in index.html

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'home',
            'about(/)': 'about', //about or /about/ will call the same function
            'work(/:id)' : 'work',
            "*path"  : "notFound"
        }
    });
    // Initiate the router
    var app_router = new AppRouter;

    app_router.on('route:home', function() {
        $("#log").html("home");
    });
    app_router.on('route:about', function() {
        $("#log").html("about");
    });
    app_router.on('route:work', function(id) {
        $("#log").html("work " + id);
    });
    app_router.on('route:notFound', function(path) {
        $("#log").html("404 " + path);
    });

    Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/post43/"});

    $(document).on("click", "a:not([data-bypass])", function(e) {
        // Get the anchor href and protcol
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        // Stop the default event to ensure the link will not cause a page refresh.
        e.preventDefault();
        Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
    });
});
```

Comment: How is this related to Backbone?

Comment: Htaccess redirects any path to index.html. Then backbone router in index.html reads these paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging, this piece of code works on IIS for me. I was looking [this guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) when converting my htaccess. I hope it will help others who are looking for this kind of solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="history" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^index$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```